# set gridview column uneditable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to set gridview column uneditable. I also tried ((BoundField)gridView1.Columns[columnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;
but it gives error of invalid index.
I don't know where to use it.
I used it in rowediting method.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        string path = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\website.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
        conn = new OleDbConnection(path);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select [email],[password] from users";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

UPDATED CODE: ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" Caption="User Info" CaptionAlign="Top" CellPadding="2" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" UseAccessibleHeader="False" Width="573px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I guess the columns are already uneditable.

Comment: columns are editable when I click the edit but When I use ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[1]).ReadOnly = true; it gives exception that the index is out of bound i used this mrthod evertwhere in th above code

Comment: can you show the HTML

Comment: i need to just set the value to asp.net gridview control

Comment: I have to see the aspx code, without that I am not able to check what is going wrong in your code

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" Caption="User Info" CaptionAlign="Top" CellPadding="2" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" UseAccessibleHeader="False" Width="573px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
GridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: what `Index` are you giving at `columnIndex`

Comment: i am giving it 1. as ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[1]).ReadOnly = true;

Comment: Try giving `0` and check.

Comment: it adds another column let me clear i am generating gridview from database and i need to programatically do that

Comment: Add `RowHeaderColumn="ReadOnly"` property to the gridview and check

Comment: how are you calling Gridview from the database